# Pyrebase is trying to import JSONDecodeError from the wrong module

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, pyrebase

I am using google Colab for collaboration purposes, Whenever I import pyrebase this error shows up.

```
import pyrebase
```

and the error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-67-d0075fed4eb1> in <cell line: 3>()
      1 import pandas as pd
      2 import numpy as np
----> 3 import pyrebase
      4 import json
      5 df = pd.read_excel('FireTable.xlsx')

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/requests/exceptions.py in <module>
      7 from urllib3.exceptions import HTTPError as BaseHTTPError
      8 
----> 9 from .compat import JSONDecodeError as CompatJSONDecodeError
     10 
     11 

ImportError: cannot import name 'JSONDecodeError' from 'requests.compat' (/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/requests/compat.py)
```

From What I understand in this kind of issue, pyrebase is trying to import the module from the requests library, not the standard one.